# Is it possible to install "Windows Phone 7 developer tools" on "Windows 7 Starter edition" and run the WP7 emulator?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, windows-7, emulation

Is it possible to install "Windows Phone 7 developer tools" on "Windows 7 Starter"?
Does the WP7 emulator run after install?

I have a old laptop Sony Vaio which has been upgrade into W7 Ultimate and VS2010 pro, but the graphic card is too old and WP7 emulator won't run.

Can anyone have try to run the WP7 emulator on a Win7 Starter edition?

Comment: ... I guess it's not possible! [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402530(v=vs.92).aspx) Windows® 7 x86 or x64 (all editions except Starter Edition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid the tools are not supported on Windows 7 starter edition.

From the [download page](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23854):

> System requirements
>   Supported Operating Systems: Windows 7, Windows Vista
>
> •Windows® Vista® (x86 and x64) with Service Pack 2 – all editions
>   except Starter Edition.
>
> •Windows® 7 (x86 and x64) – all editions
>   except Starter Edition.

You *might* get VS to run, but I think you'll hit problems with the emulator as it runs in a VM, which Windows 7 Starter won't support.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on using Windows 7 starter edition, however if the machine you are planning on using is an Intel Atom based netbook I think you may find that you struggle to run Visual Studio and the WP7 Device Emulator simultaneously.
I was certainly unable to the last time I tried on an Atom based machine, even with 3GB of RAM.